# Can I remove the "src" package from python doc generated with sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a python project and a structure like this

```
project
|-- doc
|-- src
    |-- mod_1.py
    |   |-- Class1    
    |-- package1
        |-- mod_2.py
            |-- Class2
```

I used `sphinx-apidoc` to create my documentation and the path to my submodules look like this

```
src.mod1
src.package2.mod2
```

Now I wonder, if there is a way to remove the `src` prefix?
To make the path look like this

```
mod1
package2.mod2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After raising an issue at GitHub [sphinx #3113](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3113), shimizukawa came up with a solution:

- Remove `__init__.py` from `src` folder
- Set pythonpath to `/../src` instead of `/../` in the `conf.py`