# Generate sphinx docu from docstrings not working

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a project with the following structure (which I would like to keep):

```
my_project
├── build  # here is where sphinx should dump into
├── requirements.txt
├── make.bat
├── Makefile
├── ...  # more config files
├── doc  # this is where I want sphinx files to live
│   ├── conf.py
│   └── index.rst
├── src
│   └── my_project
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── module_1
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── ...
│       └── util
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── ...
└── tests
    ├── module_1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── ...  # testing module 1
    └── util
        ├── __init__.py
        └── ...  # testing util stuff
```

I recreated it [on github](https://github.com/a-recknagel/my_project), which can be used to recreate the results by executing `my_setup.sh` within.

I want to build the documentation from docstrings. I used sphinx's quickstart to generate necessary config, but when I call `make hmtl`, the resulting docu doesn't include any docstrings from my source code, i.e. everything in `my_project/src/my_project`. Sphinx's documenation is a bit overwhelming, given that I feel that I am trying to set up something very basic.

Relevant info from config files (please tell me if I forgot something important):

**Makefile**

```
SPHINXOPTS    =
SPHINXBUILD   = sphinx-build
SPHINXPROJ    = my_project
SOURCEDIR     = doc
BUILDDIR      = build
...
```

**make.bat**

```
set SOURCEDIR=doc
set BUILDDIR=build
set SPHINXPROJ=my_project
...
```

**conf.py**

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src/my_project'))
...
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
]
...
```

---

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086048/962190) as well, but it first put a bunch of build files into `doc` that I'd rather not have there and it also didn't find any of the modules (fixed by omitting the `-F` parameter):

```
$ sphinx-apidoc -F -o doc/ src/my_project/
$ cd doc
$ make html
Running Sphinx v1.7.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 2 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] my_project.util                                                                                                                                                                                  
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'my_project'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'my_project'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'my_project.util.test_file'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'my_project'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'my_project.util'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'my_project'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... /home/arne/workspace/git/my_project/doc/my_project.rst: WARNING: document isn\'t included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] my_project.util                                                                                                                                                                                   
generating indices... genindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 4 warnings.
```

Comment: The problem might be that your original Sphinx project that was created with sphinx-quickstart gets overwritten. When you use the `-F` option, sphinx-apidoc creates a new Sphinx project (with a different conf.py, Makefile etc.).

Comment: @mzjn That was definitely a problem, using `sphinx-apidoc -o build src/my_project` instead put the files in the right place and works with the original makefile. But the resulting page still won't include any docstring info.

Comment: Somewhere you need to have one `automodule` directive for each module. You can add them by hand in index.rst (for example) or let sphinx-apidoc create additional rst files with these directives. What do your `automodule` directives look like?

Comment: [`my_module.rst`](http://dpaste.com/10J31XT), [`my_module.util.rst`](http://dpaste.com/195CG9E). There is also [`modules.rst`](http://dpaste.com/140S9QY) in there, but it doesn't have any automodule info.

Comment: This is confusing. In your project structure diagram there is nothing called `my_module`. It says that you have a package called `my_project` with `module_1` and `util` submodules.

Comment: my bad, my project isn't actually called `my_project`.. and I copied the wrong stand-in over. I think every my_module needs to be called my_project instead, and module_1's rst would look [like this](http://dpaste.com/2W1KRM6).

Comment: I think you need to use `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src/'))`.

Comment: Still nothing.. just in case, [this](http://dpaste.com/3FVHR3N) is the test file I created that I hope to extract the dosctrings from.

Comment: Minor comment, I think you mean `my_setup.sh`, and I would suggest using the first line as follows `python3 -m venv env`. Also toss in a `pip install --upgrade pip`. I'll follow up with more information if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Arne using the `my_project\SRC` layout, I found the explanation in [this thread invaluable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579500/can-i-remove-the-src-package-from-python-doc-generated-with-sphinx) as to why `SRC` is magically omitted from package names. As a complementing afterthought...

Comment: @bad_coder It's been a while since I asked this question, by now I changed my default project layout to one where the package is dev-installed before sphinx starts to build docs. That way, I don't need to handle the PYTHONPATH myself, which solved a whole class of problems for me. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155464/using-pytest-with-a-src-layer) explained me the pros and cons in that regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your MCVE.

1. rST source files must not reside in the output directory `build`, and should be in the docs source directory `docs`.  You should have done this instead: `sphinx-apidoc -o docs src/my_project`.
2. As @mzjn mentioned, you need to uncomment and add some lines to your `conf.py` to resolve the `WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module` errors.

   ```
   # -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

   # If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
   # add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
   # documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
   #
   import os
   import sys
   # sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src/'))
   ```

After those two changes, I was able to successfully build your docs with its API.