# Using pytest with a src layer

Tags: python, pytest, python-packaging

[pytest recommends](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code) including an additional directory to separate the source code within a project:

```
my_package
├── src  # <-- no __init__.py on this layer
│   └── my_package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── util_module
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── utils.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_util_module
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_utils.py
```

Sadly, they say nothing<sup>[1]</sup> about how imports in the test code should work in such a case, which work for my IDE just fine in [this naive example](https://gitlab.com/arecknag/my_package)<sup>[2]</sup>, but causes the following error with pytest:

```bash
~/my_package$ pytest

====================== test session starts ======================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/user/workspace/my_package, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors     
                                                                                                                                                                      
============================ ERRORS =============================
___ ERROR collecting tests/test_util_module/test_utils.py ___
ImportError while importing test module '/home/user/workspace/my_package/tests/test_util_module/test_utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_util_module/test_utils.py:1: in <module>
    from test.test_module.some_file import starify
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package.util_module'
!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!
```

I can fix the issue by changing the import of the test to

```py
from src.my_package.util_module.utils import starify
```

but then my IDE complaints about the `src` part being redundant, so I'd like to keep it out.

---

<sup>[1]<sub>: Not the case any more. As of version 3.7.3, pytest recommends the editable install also featured in @hoefling's answer at the top of its [good practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/goodpractices.html#install-package-with-pip).</sub></sup>

<sup>[2]<sub>: Setup is `virtualenv env -p python3.6; source env/bin/activate; pip install pytest`</sub></sup>

Comment: Are your test directories plain directories or are they packages (containing an `__init__.py` file)?

Comment: @TomDalton Every dir except the root dir and the src dir is a package. Just a sec, I'm posting a `tree .`

Comment: If you export `PYTHONPATH=".:src/"` before running the tests, does that change anything?

Comment: (I'm assuming you run the tests from the root directory)

Comment: e.g. `test $ pytest` should be `my_package $ pytest`?

Comment: @TomDalton yes, i am renaming the example right now.. it was a bit confusing I guess. Also, exporting the PYTHONPATH works as well

Comment: Now the pytest output doesn't match your directory tree :D

Comment: Alright, I reproduced structure and all, it's reproducible as it is now in the post. Exporting `PYTHONPATH` solves the issue, and it is certainly better than adding `src.` in front of all test suite imports, but I'd hope for a slightly cleaner solution that would make the repo testable as it is now.

Comment: Did you install `my_package`, i.e. does it contain a `setup.py`?

Comment: @NilsWerner No, and no. Should I always do that before testing? I'd rather run unit tests before build in the CI, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, of course you: 1) need to build the code in order to test it. 2) make the package `import`able by installing it

Comment: "of course you: 1) need to build the code in order to test it." - In the general case this is not true ,and for a lot of people (myself included) it is not desireable

Comment: And "of course you: ... 2) make the package importable by installing it", packages can be importable without being installed anywhere as long as python's package search path is configured correctly (e.g. by setting pythonpath or other tricks).

Comment: @TomDalton  And the right way to configure the search path correctly is by ... (_drum roll_) ... installing the package!

Comment: Is there any test runner that "just works"? If we already have the `python` interpreter set up to work, we shouldn't need to do more messing around. I don't want a degree in pytest.

Comment: @Dogweather are you just venting because the import system bit you, or do you seriously mean that "if `python my_code.py` works, then `python-test-runner` should just work too"? Linking library code correctly is a Tricky Problem, and any framework that tries to handle it for you will come with heavy assumptions and restrictions on how your code can be structured which may bite you much harder.

Comment: any way, [the section in the pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code) features different and more light-weight setups as well that might suite your use case better than "make it installable".

Comment: @Arne I seriously mean that. I have that expectation now after using Elixr, Rust, Gleam, and even Ruby RSpec—and coming back to Python. RSpec needs extra config, but it will auto-generate that for you.

Plus, I need to do this work with ipython shell, VS Code / Pylance, Pyright, and Python Notebook. It seems every environment needs unique setup. I think we can do better.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

#### Recommended approach for `pytest>=7`: use the `pythonpath` setting

Recently, `pytest` has added a new core plugin that supports `sys.path` modifications via the [`pythonpath` configuration value](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath). The solution is thus much simpler now and doesn't require any workarounds anymore:

`pyproject.toml` example:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src"
]
```

`pytest.ini` example:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src
```

The path entries are calculated relative to the rootdir, thus the `src` entry adds `path/to/project/src` directory to `sys.path` in this case.

Multiple path entries are also allowed: for a layout

```
repo/
├── src/
|   └── lib.py
├── src2/
|   └── lib2.py
└── tests
    └── test_lib.py
```

the configuration

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src", "src2",
]
```

or

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src src2
```

will add both `lib` and `lib2` modules to `sys.path`, so

```
import lib
import lib2
```

will both work.

#### Original answer

Adjusting the `PYTHONPATH` (as suggested in the comments) is one possibility to solve the import issue. Another is adding an empty `conftest.py` file in the `src` directory:

```
$ touch src/conftest.py
```

and `pytest` will add `src` to `sys.path`. This is a simple way to trick `pytest` into adding codebase to `sys.path`.

However, the `src` layout is usually selected when you intend to build a distribution, e.g. providing a `setup.py` with (in this case) explicitly specifying the root package dir:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


setup(
    ...
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    ...
)
```

and installing the package in the development mode (via `python setup.py develop` or `pip install --editable .`) while you're still developing it. This way, your package `my_package` is correctly integrated in the Python's site packages structure and there's no need to fiddle with `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Also, SO has an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20972950/2650249) on this topic.

Comment: I tested both solutions and both work =) thanks for the help!

Comment: This official doc might be helpful: [pytest import mechanisms and sys.path/PYTHONPATH](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/pythonpath.html)

Comment: Don't ask me why, but setting `pythonpath = src` didn't work for me, even though my main.py is directly inside `root/src/main.py`.

What did work is setting `pythonpath = .`.
I would be very glad if anyone could explain this.

Comment: `pytest.ini` should be in root directory which contains the `src` folder

Comment: Using the `pythonpath` setting in `pyproject.toml` is best because the setting is kept in the repo and automatically distributed to other developers. If for some reason you think you do need to set `PYTHONPATH` you can add an `export` to `.venv/bin/activate` for seamless support, but note this in your `README.rst` for other developers.

Comment: if you have both `pytest.ini` and `pyproject.toml`, [then](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html) `pytest.ini` files take precedence over other files, even when empty. So having correctly configured  `[tool.pytest.ini_options]` section in the `pyproject.toml` file should be enough. Then pytest will read configuration from the `pyproject.toml` file and we don't need the`pytest.ini`.

Answer (score 6):

As of PyTest 7.0.0, you can now use the `pythonpath` option to set some default entries in `sys.path`. This is the most convenient way of going about this.

In `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src/
```

In `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = "src/"
```

If you use `tox`, then you should *unset* this in its settings, so you don't accidentally test the local version, rather than the installed version.

In `tox.ini`:

```
[testenv]
commands = pytest ... -o pythonpath=
```

See the documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath

Answer (score 3):

PYTHONPATH updates weren't working for me when using github actions (known prob). Using this pytest-pythonpath install with pytest.ini file worked for me instead:

```
pip install pytest-pythonpath # accompany with python_path in pytest.ini, so PYTHONPATH is updated with location for modules under test
```

With this, basic 'pytest' command happily found all tests in subdirs, and found modules under test based on my pytest.ini (set to match source folders in pycharm)

Comment: You should be able to use `python -m pytest ...` so that the `PYTHONPATH` is available to `pytest`.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for the show, but I believe it's just possible to update `sys.path` in `tests/__init__.py` and it should work. I believe that is what the plugin does.

eg. in my case the dir structure looks like:

```
repo/
├── src/
|   └── foo.py
└── tests
    ├── pytest.ini
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── __init__.py  # update sys.path here
    ├── integration
    │   └── ...
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_foo.py
```

So in `tests/__init__.py` I just do this:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("src")
```

After this the `pytest ./tests` just works and IDE seems to be happy as well, with some caviats. Eg. isort in `VSCode` (Microsoft Python, iSort and Pylance plugins) works correctly sorting the `src` imports separately as internal, however in `vim` (ALE, pyright, isort) it mushes them together with external package imports, but I think it's probably down to difference in config that I need to investigate.

Or alternatively setting `PYTHONPATH` env variable works too:

```
PYTHONPATH=".:src" pytest ./tests
```