# How to import a file from another nested sibling directory in python

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, python-packaging

I'm am trying to import a file which is in another folder but unable to do it.
My folder structure is

```
Animals/Bird/Birds.py

Animals/Bird/__init__.py

Animals/Mammals/Mammals.py

Animals/Mammals/Testing.py

Animals/Mammals/__init__.py
```

I'm unable to access Birds.py file from Testing.py file

```
Animals/Bird/__init__.py
----------------------
name = "Bird"


Animals/Mammals/__init__.py
----------------------
name = "Mammals"


Animals/Bird/Birds.py
----------------------
print("Hello")


Animals/Mammals/Mammals.py
----------------------
print("BYE")
```

I have tried using **init**.py file for importing but could not find the solution

```
# Import classes from your brand new package
from Mammals import *

from Bird.Birds import *
```

I wanted to access Birds.py file from Testing.py file which is other directory which raising me an error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bird'"`

Comment: While there are some differences, you could use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155464/using-pytest-with-a) as a guideline. The answer lays out three different solutions of how your tests can properly import your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from ..Bird.Birds import *
```

or if you also want the Bird `__init__.py`:

```
from ..Bird import *
```

as you need to go into the parent directory first, where the `module` is located.

If you would be in the `Mammals` directory and not in `Testing.py`, you would just need one `.` in front of `Bird`:

```
from .Bird.Birds import *
```

Answer (score 1):

after some research i think you can't directly import it so you might try to extend the python reach to the directory you want by

```
import sys
sys.path.append('Animals/Bird') # directory you want to access that you might wanna put more accuratly
from Birds import *
```

Comment: Still I'm unable to the fix can you help me with the working code

Comment: also if you are using python 3, there is no need for init files any more