# Python no module named X - absolute imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Before I even start I want to say - I know, that there are like bazillion questions similar to this, but I couldn't find the answer to my problem. I have a dir structure like this:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── somelib.py
│   ├── B
│   ├── C
│   │   └── C
│   │       ├── foo.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── run.sh
```

**run.sh**:

`python3 project/C/C/foo.py`

**foo.py**:

`from project.A.somelib import somefunc`

---

VS Code actually gets the intellisense in `foo.py` - it tells me what funcitons/variables I can import from `somelib`. But when I run `run.sh`, I get this error message:

```
from project.A.somelib import somefunc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Is there a way to solve this while preserving this directory structure?

---

- adding `project/__init__.py` changed nothing
- the `sys.path` in `foo.py` looks like this:

```
['/home/dabljues/projects/project/project/C/C', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

#### restrictions:

- I can't modify neither `sys.path` in the files nor `PYTHONPATH` before running the scripts
- I can't pip-install anything
- I don't have sudo-access
- I can't create a virtualenv, since the scripts are supposed to be downloadable and quickly executable

Comment: can you add a project/__init__.py?

Comment: was one of the similar questions this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155464/using-pytest-with-a-src-layer It runs a unit test instead of a script, but the problem might be the same - you need to either make `project` installable and install it, or add the project root in some other way to the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Can you add the line `import sys; print(sys.path)` at the top of `run.sh` and include the output in your question?

Comment: Can you create a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) that is owned by your current user?

Comment: I could, but it's a script which will be downloaded many times from repo, it should be fast and I was told that it wouldn't have time to create venv

Comment: Fair enough. With that many restrictions in place a good solution might not be feasible.. I still think that the best way would be to turn everything that is not a script into an installable package and ask your users to install it. Then all the scripts would have a common well defined entrypoint. Also @dabljues, I reformatted your question a little, does it still reflect your original question?

Comment: Yes it does, I guess. Anyway, I am accepting your answer as it actually really good, if someone isn't as restricted as I am

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IDEs like VSCode or Pycharm make their own assumptions about a project, and will usually correctly link modules even if the interpreter that will ultimately run the code can't.

The reason why `project.A.somelib` can't be found is visible in your `sys.path` output, which gives you the places where python will search for modules. Since `'/home/dabljues/projects/project/project'` is not included, there is no way for python to resolve it during runtime.

---

#### A quick hack

You can just add the path manually to `sys.path`, either in the source file by running `import sys; sys.insert(0, '/home/dabljues/projects/project/project/')` in `foo.py` before any other imports happen, or by running `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/dabljues/projects/project/project/"` in your shell before `run.sh`.

---

#### Installing the project

Since it looks like you're developing a library, you might as well use the mechanisms python offers to make libraries shareable and thereby fixing any import issues. Add a minimal `setup.py` to the project root (i.e. `/home/dabljues/projects/project/project/setup.py`):

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='project',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages('project'),
)
```

And install your project in editable mode:

```sh
$ python3 -m pip install -e .
```

This will put a link in your `python3` executable's `site-packages` that points to the project root, which makes it accessible whenever you run anything with `python3`.

---

#### Tests

I included `print(__name__)` at the top of all python files to get some output.

**running run.sh without installing the package:**

```sh
$ sh run.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project/C/C/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from project.A.somelib import somefunc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

**after installing it**

```sh
$ sh run.sh 
__main__
project.A.somelib
```

As you can see, `project.C.C.foo` is executed as a script, yet it finds all imports that start with `project` because `project` is installed.

Comment: Wow, thanks for a clarification. I cannot use sys.path inserting. Then I cannot use exporting PYTHONPATH, as every script in it's directory has to be a standalone script. I got to have an option to run it from root, but also from it's own directory

Comment: So, will installing it be a valid solution?

Comment: Oh, I forgot. No sudo priviliges for me, so definitely not

Comment: well.. from a packaging point of view I'm afraid that the right answer would be "scripts shouldn't be part of a library/package".

Answer (score 3):

Run python in package mode helps.

1) Add `__init__.py` for every path:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── somelib.py
│   ├── B
│   ├── C
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── C
│   │       ├── foo.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── run.sh
```

2) Import module with relative path in foo.py:

```
from ...A.somelib import somefunc
```

3) Run python in package mode:

```
python -m project.C.C.foo
```

It works for me.

Comment: Okay, it works. But I had to update every other import in `foo.py`. For example: `from bar import baz` -> `from .bar import baz`. And I think it doesn't work when I would try to run it from it's own directory

Comment: Yes, you cannot run it from it's own directory. sys.path.append() is the only solution I can figure out for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this given your code (assuming `run.sh` just starts a script).

Are you sure it's not a case of e.g. circular imports?

```
$ mkdir -p project/A project/C/C
$ cat > project/C/C/foo.py
print('moof!')
$ cat > project/A/somelib.py
print('beef!')
$ cat > script.py
import project.A.somelib
import project.C.C.foo
$ tree
.
├── project
│   ├── A
│   │   └── somelib.py
│   └── C
│       └── C
│           └── foo.py
└── script.py
$ python3 script.py
beef!
moof!
```

Comment: Well, yeah, but you're importing those from root dir. And as you can see, I am importing `project.A.somelib` in file `project/C/C/foo.py`. Doesn't that change anything? I tried your method and it works, but I don't import anything at the root level, I do it in nested files

Answer (score 0):

Change your run.sh script to run `foo` as a module. `python3 -m proj.C.C.foo`

Comment: If I do this, I get: `/usr/bin/python3: No module named project/C/C/foo`. And if I add extension, so its `python3 -m proj.C.C.foo.py`, I get: `/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'project/C/C/foo.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project/C/C/foo.py)`

Comment: 1) Module option should be used with a . and not /                                     
2) No extension should be used                                                                     
 So, it should be as python3 -m proj.C.C.foo and not python3 -m proj.C.C.foo.py. No .py extension. Just copy paste what was written in original answer.