# How to add documentation to a python package after it has been built?

Tags: python, build, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I developed a python package that generates HTML documentation for other python packages. Let's call it `DocumentationGenerator`. It is installed in my virtual environment.

I have a python package for which I would like to generate documentation before building it. Let's call it `SomePythonPackage`.

A pipeline is set up for `SomePythonPackage` which builds the package and uploads the generated `.tar.gz` to a server. I integrated `DocumentationGenerator` to the build script using a python function `generate_documentation(*args)` to generate the documentation before the package was built so that the package could be built with its documentation. My `DocumentationGenerator` of course needs to import the package for which a documentation should be generated. I get the following error:

```
Importing library 'C:/ProjectPath/src/SomePythonPackage/path/to/lib.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SomePythonPackage'
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/ProjectPath/src/SomePythonPackage/path/to/lib.py", line 32, in <module>
from SomePythonPackage.subdirectory1.foo import bar
```

This is because there is an absolute import in one of the files of `SomePythonPackage`, which assumes the package itself is already installed.

Now I need to find some way to generate the documentation after installing the package. I have been stuck on this for some time. Currently, I build the package in the pipeline without the documentation, install it, generate the documentation, and build it again.

My question is: is there a more efficient way to do this so I don't have to build twice in my build pipeline? (since the pipeline should be preferably fast)

My goal in the end is to get a `.tar.gz` with the following structure:

```
SomePythonPackage
|  documentation/...
|  subdirectory1/...
|  subdirectory2/...
|  ...
```

**UPDATE**

My Tree looks like this:

```
ProjectPath/
| .venv/
|  |  ...
|  |  setuptools
|  |  build
|  |  DocumentationGenerator
|  \  ...
| azure-pipelines/
|  \  pipeline.yml
| dist/
|  |  some_python_package.whl
|  \  some_python_package.tar.gz
| src/
|  |  SomePythonPackage/
|  |    |  ...
|  |    |  __init__.py
|  |    |  requirements.txt
|  |    |  doc/... (which should preferably be generated before building or somehow added to the build after it)
|  \    \  ...
| __init__.py
| .gitignore
| MANIFEST.in
| pyproject.toml
| README.md
| setup.py
\ VERSION
```

I am using the `setuptools` backend with the `build` frontend.

MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include src/SomePythonPackage *
include VERSION
global-exclude .gitignore
global-exclude *.py[cod]
```

pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

And my "build script" is a few irrelevant tasks which sum up to execute:

```py
if os.path.isdir('C:/ProjectPath/dist'):
    shutil.rmtree('C:/ProjectPath/dist')
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "build", 'C:/ProjectPath',
               "--outdir", 'C:/ProjectPath/dist'], check=True)
```

Would it work to somehow add the directory `doc/` to the `some_python_package.tar.gz` file after building? I am trying this by generating a new tarfile with the old contents and `doc/` but I am somehow breaking my build. Or maybe a way to trick the imports to think that `SomePythonPackage` is already installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python no module named X - absolute imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570677/python-no-module-named-x-absolute-imports)

Comment: No, not really. Adding `C:/ProjectPath` to `sys.path` didn't fix the problem. And installing the project is my current solution which is not as efficient as I would hope. Furthermore, I would optimally like to find a solution where I don't have to change `SomePythonPackage` since the package will not always be my property. And the package which I am developing is actually `DocumentationGenerator`, which should work with any package.

Comment: Plus adding `__init__.py` to all directories and turning all absolute imports to relative imports still throws the error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your project structure/tree and the command you're using to build? What is the "build script" you are using?