# Trying to import a class from another file but my test breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-poetry

I'm trying to use prettyconf - https://github.com/osantana/prettyconf - to use a .env file.

I created a config.py file and put it in the same folder of my script.

My config.py is this one:

```
from prettyconf import config


class Settings:
    ENVIRONMENT = config(
        'ENVIRONMENT',
        default='dev',
        cast=config.option({'dev': 'dev', 'int': 'int', 'prod': 'prod'}),
    )

    LOG_LEVEL = config('LOG_LEVEL', default='INFO')
 

settings = Settings()
```

In my script I import my config.py in this way:

`from cl_uploader.config import settings`

But I got this error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cl_uploader.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cl_uploader.config import settings
  File "/home/myfolder/Doing/folder/cl_uploader/cl_uploader.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cl_uploader.config import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cl_uploader.config'; 'cl_uploader' is not a package
```

I tried to change to a relative path like this:

`from .config import settings`

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cl_uploader.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .config import settings
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

But if a let like this:

`from config import settings`

It works! But...

My tests starts to break and I get this msg:

```
____________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_cl_uploader.py _____________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/myfolder/Doing/folder/tests/test_cl_uploader.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:511: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:704: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:152: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
tests/test_cl_uploader.py:10: in <module>
    from cl_uploader.cl_uploader import check_stack_exists
cl_uploader/cl_uploader.py:7: in <module>
    from config import settings
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
====================================== short test summary info ======================================
ERROR tests/test_cl_uploader.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================= 1 error in 0.25s ==========================================
```

My tree folder is set this way:

```
.
├── cl_uploader
│   ├── cl_uploader.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── resources
│       └── teste.yaml
├── file.tmp
├── local.env
├── Makefile
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_cl_uploader.py
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using pytest with a src layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155464/using-pytest-with-a-src-layer)

Comment: Your project doesn't have a src layer, but the fix would work anyway - if you're writing something that looks like a package, make it installable. It will solve any import errors without resorting to hacking `sys.path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already in the `cl_uploader` folder.  Try:  `from config import settings`.

In `__init__.py` add this:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Then, all files in this directory will be on `sys.path`. Might want to change the filename to `cl_config.py` to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Your package is called `cl_uploader` and you have a module `cl_uploader` within this package. Avoid this duplication of names.

By default python will look in the current working directory first if it can find the module or package, before going through other places.

So when you are inside the `cl_uploader` folder, it will pickup the `cl_uploader` module instead of the package. If you are outside it will pickup the package.

In summary: rename `cl_uploader.py` to something else and everything will work fine.