# Pytest fails with relative imports

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest, python-import

I have the following project structure in Pycharm -

```
project/
    src/
        main.py
        config/
            __init__.py
            settings.py
        package1/
            __init__.py
            client.py # Imports settings from config using -> from ..config import settings
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test.py
```

So here my client.py imports settings -

```
from ..config import settings
```

main.py imports client -

```
from package1.client import clientFunction # ClientFunction is the method defined inside client.py
```

I use pytest to run the tests. So now when i run the pytest configuration, in my test cases i import main. I dont see any errors in my code but when the tests run it says -

```
from ..config import settings
E   ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

How can i fix this? Seems like pytest is taking a different path to execute the tests and hence the relative imports are going beyond the top level.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not 100% sure about the relative import syntax but there seems to be a space in the last import `.. config`. There's also no `__init__.py` in the `src` making it a namespace package, I'm not sure if relative imports work in such a case. If you are installing the package just `from config import settings` should work (which might not if you don't install the package but works after installing it).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Changed it. The src folder is the source folder which has packages within it. Is it ideal to have the __init__.py in it? What do you mean by installing it ? I have a venv where the system imports happened based on poetry but these are packages written by me.

Comment: maybe setting the pytest working directory can fix it?

Comment: mmm, the pytest working directory is mostly about where you can just type `pytest something` and the pytest configuration file takes all its paths relative to that, see [the configuration files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/customize.html). About using a `src` layout I recommend [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50155464) together with [Installing from a local src tree](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree). I really don't know about poetry specifics...

Comment: marking the src directory as source root did the trick. Thanks for your help

Comment: Good to know it worked out for you.