# Poetry run pytest only works with __init__.py in tests/ directory

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, importerror, python-poetry

Poetry and pytest are relatively new to me and I am seeking to understand a specific behavior.

I have created a project with poetry, and I have added pytest as a dependy with `poetry add --group dev pytest`. As a result, here are the relevant line from `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.2.0"
```

Here is the project/modules structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── cli.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── run.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── tests
    └── test_cli.py
```

In `test_cli.py` I am importing the cli module with `from app.core.cli import *`

With this particular setup, running `poetry run pytest` fails with:

```
tests/test_cli.py:2: in <module>
    from app.core.cli import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

However, if I invoke a `poetry shell` and run `python3 -m pytest tests/` it works.

It also works if I create an `__init__.py` in the `tests/` directory.

I have seen a similar issue described [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/87) but I do not understand how it was resolved. One the suggestions to include include the project root name in the import statement did not help.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73378741/21006666), but it also did not work.

I was under the impression that an `__init__.py` is not necessary in `tests/` and that `poetry run pytest` should work without it.

Comment: could you try adding sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "..")) to the test_cli.py file before the import statement. You can find more information about finding he path to parent directory here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005822/what-does-os-path-abspathos-path-joinos-path-dirname-file-os-path-pardir)

Comment: Your setup looks ok, so maybe there is a problem with the installation of the project in the virtual environment. Open pyproject.toml and under [tool.poetry], check that name = "app". If it's different I think that poetry does not find your package somehow.

Comment: @edd313 In pyproject.toml name is not set to "app", it's set to the name of the whole project / the root directory name. In any case, what confuses me most is that invoking an interactive poetry shell then the paths are correctly set, but not with `poetry run`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is (1) without the `test/__init__.py` file why does `poetry run pytest` not behave the same as spawning the poetry shell and running pytest there? (2) is the `test/__init__.py` file a hard requirement and best practice and should always be there?