# How to tell unit tests where the package library is in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, testing, github-actions

I have built a python library and I have unit tests running inside GitHub Actions but unit tests are failing for this reason.

```
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.7/x64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test/foo_test.py:11: in <module>
    from mylib import Foo
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

The reason of the error is because of my directory structure, since `mylib` is inside the `src` directory.

```
my_project/
|-- src/
|   |-- mylib/
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- foo.py
|
|-- tests/
|   |-- test_mylib.py (imports mylib.foo.Foo) no src prefix
|
|-- setup.py
```

`pytest test` in pycharm works because I have told my IDE where the sources (src) and the package (mylib) is:

how can I execute tests without requiring prefix src for my test files.

## setup.py

```
packages=find_packages(where='src'),
package_dir={'': 'src'},
```

## Attempt

I created a file `pytest.ini` with the content but it did't work (Unit tests couldn't find my package under src directory)

```
[pytest]
srcpaths = src
```

Comment: "I created a file pytest.ini with the content but it did't work" - how did you decide to try this? Where did you put the file? What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: didn't work -> the unit tests couldn't find my package under src directory,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155464/using-pytest-with-a-src-layer)

**pytest.ini example:**

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src
```